# Expected number of steps for a random walk- robot

Tags: probability, markov-chains, expectation, random-walk

A robot is located at the top-left corner of a m x n grid

The robot is trying to reach the bottom-right corner of the grid, he can move randomly in any of the directions: up, down, left, right.

What is the expected steps for him to take before reaching the bottom right?

(Obviously the minimum steps for him to take is just : m+n, however he could move in any directions at any steps so this would complex things up... any thoughts? Possibly Markov Chains?)

Comment: There are three cases: either the robot is in the bottom row, or in the right column, in which case there is a probability of traveling to the corner, or the robot is in the rest of the grid, in which case there is a probability of traveling to the bottom row or the right column.